# Cannot select a checkbox in codeception

Tags: testing, automation, codeception, acceptance

Here is the code which I have used to select a checkbox:

## create-event-form this is the form id and checkbox name "published". I have used this sometimes its working and sometimes its not. totally confused!

$I->checkOption('#create-event-form input[type=checkbox]');

but it's not working!

can anybody suggest where i'm wrong.

Comment: What module do you use? Please provide an example of HTML.

Comment: Thanks for asking @naktibalda , issue came because of laravel debugger strip developer do that on staging sometimes!